# Snowflake ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES doesn't show me transient table details

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use the query below to get the information of transient tables on my whole account and unable to fetch any result for that.

There are two transients table already created and I can access them. All are done from the highest role accountadmin only.

`select * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."TABLES" WHERE TABLE_TYPE <> 'BASE TABLE';`

Gives me empty.

If I do with use DATABASE TRANSIENT_DB;
show tables history;
I get both transient and temporary table I created, I would like to like all the tables that are transients/temporary across the account and not under database alone. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

as per Snowflake there is a latency From 45 minutes to 3 hours (varies by view) for the information to be available in the Schema.

You can test this by yourself and will see the objects are not avialbe as sson as you create but are available in information_schema

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html

```
create table Nor_tab(fld1 varchar2(100));
create transient table tran_tab(fld1 varchar2(100));
select * from snowflake.account_usage.tables where table_name like 'NOR%';
select * from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'NOR%';
```